# Arrays and List Project

Tags: python

I've been working on this program which calls the name of a person and determines the BMI, then returns if they are overweight, underweight and normal weight but I can get the program to produce all names with BMI. I either get one name and all the correct BMI, or I get all the names and the 5 of the last BMI. Please help

```
# Individual Names

individuals = ["Claire", "Robbie", "Matt", "Lois", "Michelle"]
for individual in individuals:
    print("Individuals:", individual)

heights = []
for individual in individuals:
    height = int(input("Height (in) for " + individual))
    heights.append(height**2)

print(heights)

weights = []
for individual in individuals:
    weight = int(input("Weight (lbs) for " + individual))
    weights.append(weight*703)

print(weights)

#define function for BMI

bmis = []
bmis = [x/y for x, y in zip(weights, heights)]

for individual in individuals:
    print()
for bmi in bmis:
    print(individual) and print(bmi)
    

for individual in individuals:
    if bmi > 30:
        print(individual, ", is OVERWEIGHT")
    elif bmi < 20:
        print(individual, ", is UNDERWEIGHT")
    else:
        print(individual, ", is within the NORMAL WEIGHT")
```

Comment: `print(individual) and print(bmi)` makes little sense since print statements are not Boolean values. You probably intend `print(individual,bmi)`. Your intention behind `print()` (with nothing printed) in a loop is also obscure.

Comment: I'm learning so what would make the most sense and produce the correct results

Answer (score 1):

The reason you only get one individual to `print` is because your `print` statement in the `for individual in individuals` loop is empty.

Comment: what do you mean it's empty? When I switch the for statements I get all the individual names

Comment: What is the purpose of `for individual in individuals: print()`? What are you expecting that code to do?

Comment: Print each individual with the corresponding BMI

Comment: What is in between the parentheses in the print statement? (It is an empty print statement, so will only print blank lines)

Comment: Maybe you meant `print(individual)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Individual Names

individuals = ["Claire", "Robbie", "Matt", "Lois", "Michelle"]
for individual in individuals:
    print("Individuals:", individual)

heights = []
for individual in individuals:
    height = int(input("Height (in) for " + individual +': '))
    heights.append(height ** 2)

print(heights)

weights = []
for individual in individuals:
    weight = int(input("Weight (lbs) for " + individual+': '))
    weights.append(weight * 703)

print(weights)

# define function for BMI

bmis = []
bmis = [x / y for x, y in zip(weights, heights)]

for individual, bmi in zip(individuals, bmis):
    print(individual + '\'s bmi is: ', bmi)

for individual in individuals:
    if bmi > 30:
        print(individual + " is OVERWEIGHT")
    elif bmi < 20:
        print(individual + " is UNDERWEIGHT")
    else:
        print(individual + " is within the NORMAL WEIGHT")
```

But I wonder why `weight * 703`?

Comment: I had to add some more code to the if/else statements to make it work but it works great now thanks